# Как реализуется синтезатор?

Tags: javascript, аудио, web-audio

Здравствуйте! Я делаю приложение в котором нужно будет при нажатии клавиши проигрывать звук. Как на пианино: пока нажата клавиша, звук играет, если отпустил. звук выключается.
Как это можно реализовать, какие-нибудь мысли, советы?
Кода пока что нет, так как я еще ничего не смог сделать.

Своя идея была следующая: у нас есть звуковой файл какой-нибудь тональности. При долгом нажатии на клавишу мы просто будет отматывать аудио немного назад, то есть у нас получится synth, протяжный звук. Аудио будет звучать как бы циклически.

Answer (score 2):

Синтез звука - дело творческое. Начните с этой [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/236703/)

Коротко:

синтезаторы бывают

- FM - генерируют синусы-косинусы, комбинируют, фильтруют и получается новый альбом Stereolab
- Wavetable - содержат банки заранее записанных семплов, которые воспроизводят, изменяя высоту (то, что вы примерно предлагаете). Дешевы звучат паршиво, зайдите в любой кабак с "живой" музыкой, услышите именно это.
- Сэмплерные - В студию закатывают настоящий рояль Стенвей, обставляют микрофонами и записывают каждую клавишу с кучей вариантов. Звучат неотличимо от настоящего Стенвея, стоят - как полтора Стенвея.

Comment: Спасибо вам за статью. Эти примеры были очень кстати :)

Answer (score 2):

Топикстартеру на заметку.

Музыкальный инструмент, например, гитара или пианино при извлечении одной ноты содержит помимо основной гармоники множество высших гармоник (кратных основной) и множество некратных, тембр и прочее.

Защипнуть струну можно множеством способов, будет меняться атака звука, на сустейн сильно влияют установленные струны, даже заточка ногтей влияет кардинально. Принципиально важно направление удара по струне.

Различаются очень сильно тирандо и апояндо (хотя нужно стремиться, чтобы они звучали похоже). Звук скольжения большого пальца при смене позиции барре - отдельная песня. Легато двух нот - совсем не то же самое, что и две ноты друг за другом.

С духовыми и клавишными всё тоже самое, не думайте, что это только гитар касается.

Если всего этого не будет -- звук будет очень ненатуральный. Отделаться одной синусоидой никак не получится.

Я НЕ отговариваю писать программу. Не предлагаю конкретных алгоритмов. Просто показываю, что задача в хорошем исполнении будет намного сложнее, чем вам кажется на первый взгляд. Либо сразу настраивать себя на то, что приложение будет совсем игрушечным, учебным.

Судя по тегу `javascript` это действительно будет достаточно условное приложение.

Comment: @A K, Спасибо вам за ответ. Приложение, в принципе, нужно для себя, чтобы чему-то новому научиться. :)